# Jackson2 objectmapper is not mapping request to object

Tags: java, json, maven, objectmapper, jackson2

## dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" cache-period="31556926" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/templates/**" location="/resources/templates/" cache-period="31556926" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.demo.model.CompetencyMapping</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


 <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
    </beans>
```

I have used the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.

## pom.xml : just added the com.fasterxml.jackson.core "databind" and "core" references

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcompui</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pcompui Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.security.core>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.security.core>
        <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Mail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- joda time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- java servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AOP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>





        <!-- EHCache Core APIs -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.6.9</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- EHCache uses slf4j for logging -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.5</version> </dependency> -->

        <!--connector jar for db -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.metaparadigm</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-rpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- mysql dependency -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JACKSON Dependency -->     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>pcompui</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now when the request is send with json, the controller method does not get invoked. If I delete the method parameter "@RequestBody DateRequest systemDate" the method gets invoked with the console showing the statements.

Controller used is @RestController

```
//headers={"Accept=application/json", "Content-Type=application/json"}
    @RequestMapping(value="/retrieveStartandEndDates",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"application/json"} , headers={"Accept=application/json", "Content-Type=application/json"})
    public RetrieveStartEndDates retrieveStartandEndDates(@RequestBody DateRequest systemDate){
        //RetrieveStartEndDates systemDate = new RetrieveStartEndDates();
        System.out.println("inside controller:::"+systemDate.getSystemDate());
        RetrieveStartEndDates obj = new RetrieveStartEndDates();
        obj = schemeService.getStartAndEndDates(systemDate.getSystemDate());
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
        return obj;
    }
```

DateRequest is a simple DTO object

```
package com.demo.vo;

public class DateRequest {

    private String SystemDate;
    private String dest;
    public String getSystemDate() {
        return SystemDate;
    }
    public void setSystemDate(String systemDate) {
        this.SystemDate = systemDate;
    }
    public String getDest() {
        return dest;
    }
    public void setDest(String dest) {
        this.dest = dest;
    }

}
```

## JSON Request

{SystemDate: "12/23/2016", dest: "retrieveStartandEndDates"}

Not sure on what have I missed here. Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: irrespective of everything change `private String SystemDate;` to `private String systemDate;` please

Comment: Use `objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);`

Comment: @SagarReddy : this was done as the json request sends SystemDate in upperCamelcase

Comment: @SagarReddy: Do I have to add a custom object mapper

Comment: Read here for naming convention in java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @SagarReddy: sorry but you are deviating from the topic. Variable naming convention is known to me. Changed it to upper camel case as the json request had upper camel case. However on your suggestion I changed the variable to lower camel case but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instead of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Comment: Even this did not help